# Roots of unity over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, roots-of-unity, multiplicative-order

Let $H = \{\omega, \omega^2, \dots, \omega^{n-1}, \omega^n = 1\}$ be the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $n$-th roots of unity, generated by the primitive $n$-th root of unity $\omega$.

I am trying to prove (without any success) the following:

- Prove that $-\omega^i = \omega^{i + n/2}$, for every $i \in {1,2,\dots, n}$, i.e., that the additive inverse of $\omega^i$ is $\omega^{i + n/2}$.

Why is this true? I was trying with the sum $\omega^i + \omega^{i+n/2}$, but did not arrived to anything.

Comment: $-1=\omega^{n/2}$ is the unique element of order two (for $n>2$).

Comment: Are you having difficulty showing $\omega^{n/2} \neq 1$?

Comment: I was yes, but now I see that by definition of being a primitive root of unity it is impossible that $\omega^{n/2} = 1$, and hence the only possibility is that $\omega^{n/2} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be even.

If $w^n=1$, then $w^{n/2} = -1$ and so $w^{i+n/2} = -w^i$.

Comment: Why $\omega^{n/2} = -1$? Because it is impossible it to be equal to $1$?

Comment: $\omega$ is considered primitive by hypothesis. So $n$ is the minimum positive exponent that can yield $1$ over base $\omega$.